# How to check type of object received from API in Type script?

Tags: typescript, exception

Hi I am developing web application in angular 2. I am working on exception handling mechanism. I have created one model which is same as object I will be receiving from server(ERROR DTO).

Below is my code for error handler.

```
protected handleError(error, continuation: () => Observable<any>) {
        if (error.status == 401) {
            this.appContextService.redirectForLogin();
        }
        else if (typeof error == ErrorDTO) {
            return Observable.throw(error);
        }
        else {

            return Observable.throw(error);
        }
    }
```

APIs can throw objects other than my ErrorDTO also. I want to to handle this condition. The second else statement typeof error == ErrorDTO not working. Here I want to check whether error DTO I am getting is same type of ErrorDTO. This particular statement is throwing error Operator ==cannot be applied to types string andtype of error DTO. Can someone help me to fix this? Thanks.

Comment: `typeof` returns a string. I suggest you rethink your design. Hint: any design that would accommodate this in TypeScript would work equally well in JavaScript

Comment: okay thanks. May I know is there any way to handle this condition?

Comment: You can store an arbitrary string anywhere in your response and test it against whatever you want. Its fairly arbitrary however. You should, as much as possible, use http status codes (as you have already with 401) to delineate errors. Also, _please_ remember that there is nothing TypeScript specific here, it is all about JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach won't work.

For starters, `typeof error` will most surely return `'object'` always, except if `error` is `undefined`. Then it will return `'undefined'`.

You might be thinking of `instanceof`, that works more similarly to what you want: `(new Number(23)) instanceof Number` -> `true`.

However, the problem is that if that `ErrorDTO` is an interface, then when transpiling the code the type information will disapperar (you can't use `instanceof` with an interface). You could declare it as class, but, if the object `error` is the result of parsing the JSON returned by a service (and I assume it is), then it will always be just a plain `object`. `instanceof`, after all, uses prototypes to determine whether an object is an instance of another. Every object that results from parsin JSON has `Object.prototype` as its prototype:

You might have something like:

```
class ErrorDTO { ... }

// in a service:
(...).subscribe({ error: error => error as ErrorDTO});
```

That might work in TypeScript, but, if you do:

```
error instanceof ErrorDTO
```

You'll get `false`, because you're telling TypeScript that `error` is of type `ErrorDTO`, but the truth is that it isn't, even if it shares the same properties.

My advice is that you determine your errors in another way. Maybe have your errors have a `errorCode` property in your backend, then, you can have an interface in your client code:

```
interface BaseError {
    errorCode: number
    status: number
    // ... other props ...
}
```

You could have other error interfaces derive from `BaseError`. Then, your `handleError` method would accept an object of type `BaseError`:

```
protected handleError(error: BaseError, continuation: () => Observable<any>) {
    if (error.status === 401) {
        ...
    } else switch (error.errorCode) {
          case XXX:
             ...
             break;
          case YYY:
             ...
             break;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you.